# how to set the length in an xml file?

Tags: c#

I need to set the length of the ContractId field to 25 max. how can I do that?
in other way can I use the substring and how can I use I tried to use it but it works find when the field has value but when the field has no value it throws error so I wonder how can I use substring without causing this error.

```
                       new XElement(ns + "projectInfo",
                           new XElement(ns + "awardingBody", string.Empty),
                           new XElement(ns + "contractAgencyID", String.Empty),
                           new XElement(ns + "contractAgency", IsLcpCertified ? (certStatusRecord.ContractorProject.IsSub == true ? 
                                              certStatusRecord.ContractorProject.PrimeContractorName : certStatusRecord.ContractorProject.AwardingAgency) :
                                              certStatusRecord.ContractorProject.PrimeContractorId == null ? accountName : certStatusRecord.ContractorProject.PrimeContractor.Name),
                           new XElement(ns + "projectName", ""),
                           new XElement(ns + "projectID", certStatusRecord.Project.DIRProjectId),
                           new XElement(ns + "awardingBodyID", ""),
                           new XElement(ns + "projectNum", ""),
                           new XElement(ns + "contractID", **certStatusRecord.ContractorProject.ContractId**),
                           new XElement(ns + "projectLocation",
                               new XElement(ns + "description", ""),
                               new XElement(ns + "street", ""),
                               new XElement(ns + "city", ""),
                               new XElement(ns + "county", ""),
                               new XElement(ns + "state", ""),
                               new XElement(ns + "zip", ""))),
                       new XElement(ns + "payrollInfo",
                           new XElement(ns + "statementOfNP", certStatusRecord.Performing == "YES" ? false : true),
```

Comment: Please show us what you tried, and the error you got when you tried it. Also tell us the data type of `certStatusRecord.ContractorProject.ContractId`.

Comment: Are you using a schema?  String.Empty should work when there is no schema.  So the error must be coming from a schema.

Comment: the field is (varchar (50), null)